# Submit for from jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to disable the submit buttons of many forms on many different pages after they are clicked, in order for the form to be only submitted once.

I know the proper way to check for double submissions is better done server-side rather than just disabling a button, but I'm looking for a simple solution that should do for now.

Here is one of the buttons:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Here is the script I wrote

```
$(document).ready(function(){        

         $("input").each(function(index){
             //find all submit buttons with value "Save"
            if($(this).attr("value")=="Save"){
                console.log(index);
                $(this).click(function(){

                //disable the button
                $(this).attr("disabled","true");
                console.log("save btn clicked");

                //submit the form
                var form = $(this).closest("form");
                console.log(form.attr("action"));

                form.submit();          


                });

            } 

         });



     });
```

Everything works fine until the part where I try to submit, the button disables just fine.The problem is that it's not submitting (it does without this script).

Why is it not submitting? Did I fail to find the form or .. ?

Comment: if its working fine what is the problem?

Comment: @CoderJohn forgot the most basic part ... ask the question

Comment: Can you show me the HTML code for button's? May be you have used <button> instead of <input type="button" /> ??

Comment: Is the submit input inside the `form`?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I just looked and there's a </form> right after the button

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
 $(form).submit();
```

instead of

```
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('form:has(input[value="Save"])').on('submit', function() {
  alert('form submitted');
  $('input[value="Save"]', this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
input[disabled="disabled"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```